# Issue bulk creation of users in AD

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to create kind of a solution to create thousands of accounts in AD add them to specific group or for service accounts add them to specific OU. Keep a log of what was done and what the errors are.

The script ingest a csv file with the following headers.

SamAccountName,name,password,ou,domain,isAdded

```
$Domain  = [system.directoryservices.activedirectory.domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name
$NewUserADGroup = 'Print Operators'
$NewUsersList = Import-Csv .\bulk_user1.csv | Where-Object{$_.domain -like "$Domain"}
$NewUsersList | ForEach-Object{
              $NewUserAttributes = @{
              SamAccountName    = $_.SamAccountName
              name              = $_.name
              #path              = $_.parentou
              #UserPrincipalName = $_."samAccountName" + "@lovely.Local"
              AccountPassword   = (convertto-securestring "$NewUsersList.password" -AsPlainText -Force)
              Enabled           = $true
              #Server            = $dcname
              #isAdded = $Issue
              }
              try{
                 #Create new User and add to specific group
                 New-ADUser $NewUserAttributes
                 Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $NewUserADGroup -Members $_.SamAccountName
                 #Delete Specific User
                 #Remove-ADUser -Identity $_.SamAccountName
                 }catch{
                        Write-Warning $_
                        $Issue  = $_.ToString()   
                        }
                        $count = $count + 1 
                        Write-Host  $_.SamAccountName " " $_.Name " " $_.SamAccountName.Enabled " Total:" $NewUsersList.Count + "Processed:" $count
                        $NewUserAttributes| Select-Object -Property SamAccountName,name,AccountPassword,Enabled,isAdded | Export-Csv ".\$Domain.NewAccountsCreatedStatus.csv"

}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
WARNING: The name provided is not a properly formed account name
```

When I look at the variable

```
$NewUserAttributes
```

I do see the name and the value:

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                  
Enabled                        True                                                                                                                                                   
name                           bfmbsngfilexfer2                                                                                                                                       
AccountPassword                System.Security.SecureString                                                                                                                           
SamAccountName                 bfmbsngfilexfer2
```

Comment: `New-ADUser $NewUserAttributes` --> `New-ADUser @NewUserAttributes`. Splatting a Hashtable uses syntax `@params`, not `$params`

Comment: Thanks Theo, This work the account is created but now it won't add them to the group and in the output file all the variables are empty.

Comment: I think it failed when it tried to add the users to the group WARNING: Cannot find an object with identity: 'bfmbsngfilexfer1' under: 'DC=Testcct,DC=cct'.

Comment: Capture the new user with `$rookie = New-ADUser @NewUserAttributes -PassThru` then add to the group with `Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $NewUserADGroup -Members $rookie`

Comment: Also, use `-ErrorAction Stop` on the `New-ADUser` and `Add-ADGroupMember` cmdlets, so the code enters the catch block on non-terminating errors too.

Comment: Thanks Theo. I change the SamAccountName = Name and it worked with no errors. Now All i have to figure out is how to capture all that and if there is any errors in to the log file I'm creating at the end. It's still empty only headers.

Comment: Hm still don't see the results in the export file. I only see the header.

Comment: Why are they not getting exported to the output file from the hash table?

Comment: Typing on the phone now, but I'll try and give you a proper answer tomorrow

Comment: ok thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As promised, below a rewrite of your code.
I have inserted comments to hopefully explain what the code does:

```
$Domain         = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain().Name
$NewUserADGroup = 'Print Operators'
$successCount   = 0
$NewUsersList   = Import-Csv .\bulk_user1.csv | Where-Object { $_.domain -eq $Domain } | ForEach-Object {
    # capture the human readable password for output use
    $password = $_.password
    $userParams = @{
        SamAccountName    = $_.SamAccountName
        Name              = $_.name
        Path              = $_.parentou
        UserPrincipalName = '{0}@lovely.Local' -f $_.SamAccountName
        AccountPassword   = ConvertTo-SecureString $_.password -AsPlainText -Force
        Enabled           = $true
        #Server           = $dcname
    }
    try{
        # Create new User and add to specific group
        $user = New-ADUser @userParams -PassThru -ErrorAction Stop
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $NewUserADGroup -Members $user -ErrorAction Stop
        # add the 'isAdded' element to the $userParams hashtable
        $userParams['isAdded'] = $true
        $successCount++
    }
    catch{
        Write-Warning $_.Exception.Message
        $userParams['isAdded'] = $false  
    }
    # output a PsCustomObject with values taken from the Hashtable
    # AccountPassword is a SecureString, which will be of no use to you..
    # Output the human readable password instead so you can inform the new users.
    [PsCustomObject]$userParams | Select-Object SamAccountName, Name,
                                                @{Name = 'Password'; Expression = {$password}},
                                                Enabled, isAdded
}

# output
# use '@($NewUsersList)' to force it as array, so the Count property is accurate
if (@($NewUsersList).Count) { 
    Write-Host ('Processed: {0} Succeeded: {1}' -f $NewUsersList.Count, $successCount) -ForegroundColor Green
    $NewUsersList | Export-Csv ".\$Domain.NewAccountsCreatedStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation
}
else {
    Write-Host 'No users successfully processed!' -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Thanks Theo that's amazing. I ended up diching the hash table because it was to much work capturing the results in a nice table format.